# Is there any way to count the number of times this player chooses "1"

Tags: java

I'm making a game where there are two players. Each time a user enters one through the scanner input, they move forward. I'm trying to find a way to count the number of times the player enters one to set to how many times a player can enter 1.

```
System.out.print("\n" );
System.out.print( name1 + " Please Enter 1 to Throw Your Dice: ");
choice = sr.nextInt();
if(choice == 1) {
    dicenum1 = player1.throwDice();
    System.out.println("Your Dice Number is " + dicenum1);
    currentPosition = player1.getPlayerPosition() + dicenum1;
```

Comment: Something like `selectedOne++;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Player** class add a instance variable named **playerDiceThrows**:

```
private int playerDiceThrows;
```

then create a Getter method in the same class:

```
public int getPlayerDiceThrows() {
    return this.playerDiceThrows;
}
```

Again, within the same class add this line within the **throwDice()** method:

```
this.playerDiceThrows++;
```

When you want to know how many dice throws the player had done you can use:

```
int throws = player1.getPlayerDiceThrows();
System.out.println(player1.getName() + " threw the dice " + throws + " times.");
```